# Using Underscore restructure the JSON

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Original JSON

```
    var dataJson = [{
      "MID" : "NTE",
      "TNAME" : "gGAR",
      "MVALUE" : 6
    }, {
      "MID" : "NTP",
      "TNAME" : "gGAR",
      "MVALUE" : 50
    }, {
      "MID" : "NTR",
      "TNAME" : "gGAR",
      "MVALUE" : 12
    }, {
      "MID" : "NTE",
      "TNAME" : "gRRR",
      "MVALUE" : 1
    }, {
      "MID" : "NTP",
      "TNAME" : "gRRR",
      "MVALUE" : 100
    }, {
      "MID" : "NTR",
      "TNAME" : "gRRR",
      "MVALUE" : 1
    }];
```

Need to group by "TNAME" and after all the group taking first three objects based on "MID" and modify the JSON structure like

Expected output JSON:

```
        var Convert = [
        {
            "GGARMVALUENTE":6,
            "GGARMVALUENTP":50,
            "GGARMVALUENTR":12,
            "GRRRMVALUENTE":1,
            "GRRRMVALUENTP":100,
            "GRRRMVALUENTR":1
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far in js ...

Comment: `Original JSON` - that's an Object, not JSON

Comment: That's a simple Map operation, really.. no actual aggregation.

Comment: I do not understand the output structure. Either have a hashMap or have objects to uniquely identify values. Here array seems unnecessary.

Comment: I have around 21 array of object in my original json so I need to restructure the json based TNAME. Please refer this http://jsfiddle.net/kqvcyp90/443/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kqvcyp90/445/

Comment: var convert = []; var buffer = {}; dataJson.map(data => ({ [\`"${data.TNAME.toUpperCase()}MVALUE${data.MID}"\`]: data.MVALUE })).forEach(value => { Object.assign(buffer, value) }); convert.push(buffer); console.log(convert);

Comment: You don't need `UnderscoreJS` for such small task. Use `VanillaJS`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @asissuthar for your comment, It's working for single array of object but in my case, I have around 27 array of objects. Please refer this http://jsfiddle.net/kqvcyp90/446/ and try to get my expected output in fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it works according to your requirements. Just Solved Puzzling Question. :)

```
function restructure (data) {
  let convert = []
  let buffer = null
  let pairs = data.map(d => {
    return [`${d.TNAME.toUpperCase()}MVALUE${d.MID}`, d.MVALUE] 
  })
  pairs.forEach((p, i) => {
    let name = p.shift()
    let value = p.shift()
    let pair = {
      [name]: value
    }
    if (buffer && buffer[name]) {
      convert.push(buffer)
      delete buffer
      buffer = pair
    } else {
      if (buffer) {
        Object.assign(buffer, pair)
      } else {
        buffer = pair
      }
      if (pairs.length === i + 1) {
        convert.push(buffer)
        delete buffer
      }
    }
  })
  return convert
}

console.log(restructure(dataJson))
```